# Twilio Programmable Voice Custom Params Issue

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

We aren't able to receive customerparameters sent from the caller side.
Here how we are sending

```
  func performVoiceCall(uuid: UUID, client: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> 
      Void) {
      let connectOptions = ConnectOptions(accessToken: accessToken) { builder in
      builder.params = [twimlParamTo: self.callToUserId, "displayName": "zeshan"] 

       builder.uuid = uuid
    }

    let call = TwilioVoiceSDK.connect(options: connectOptions, delegate: self)
    activeCall = call
    activeCalls[call.uuid!.uuidString] = call
    callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler
 }
```

and here how we are receiving but cannot get any customer parameter at call receiving end

```
     func callInviteReceived(callInvite: CallInvite) {
       NSLog("callInviteReceived:")

       UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: kCachedBindingDate)

       let callerInfo: TVOCallerInfo = callInvite.callerInfo
       if let verified: NSNumber = callerInfo.verified {
       if verified.boolValue {
          NSLog("Call invite received from verified caller number!")
       }
   }

   let from = (callInvite.from ?? "Voice Bot").replacingOccurrences(of: "client:", with: "")
   let customParam = callInvite.customParameters?["displayName"]

   // Always report to CallKit
   reportIncomingCall(from: from, uuid: callInvite.uuid)
   activeCallInvites[callInvite.uuid.uuidString] = callInvite
   }
```

customParam is received null
Please advice

Comment: Often, it is easier to look at the TwiML your code returns, you can usually identify the issue quickly, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/changelog#new-features_9.

Comment: In your TwiML application you should be returning TwiML including `<Dial><Client>` and to send the custom parameters on to the other participant in the call you should set those as `<Parameter>` elements within the `<Client>`. Are you doing this? Can you share your server side code for the TwiML application?

Comment: Oh cool, I added it as an answer, so that others can see what worked here easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set parameters through the Twilio Voice SDK `connect` method, that send the parameters to the webhook of your TwiML application.

In order to send those parameters on so that they can be read by the Twilio Voice SDK client receiving an incoming call you need to set them again using [the `<Parameter>` TwiML element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client#custom-parameters) that is nested within the `<Client>` element. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Dial>
     <Client>
        <Identity>user-jane</Identity>
        <Parameter name="displayName" value="zeshan"/>
      </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```